# what this code mean ? can split() method be applied on anything other than a string?

Tags: java

What is the result of compiling and running the following program with the `java Split1 a1+b3-c5=4x [12345][+-=]`in command prompt?

```
public class Split1
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        System.out.println((args[0].split(args[1])).length);
    }  
}
```

The output of this code is `4`.

I am confused if we can apply this on such arguments how is the output `4`?

What I understand from this code is `args[0]` is `a1+b3-c5=4x` and `args[1]` is `[12345][+-=]`. There is no matching pattern so it wont split and the output is `1`.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: `args[1]` is a `regular expresison`. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: so ? how is the output 4 ?

Comment: split returns an array, whose length is `4`.

Comment: There is 4 groups of letters which is in between the regex matches.

Comment: A split method can be executed on each instance of each class that provides an implementation of a split method. It won't always be the same functionality, though. The split method is a String method that basically replaces the use of StringTokenizer, so it would be ridiculous attempting to call this on anything but a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `a1+b3-c5=4x` will be splitted at 1,2,3,4,5 which is followed by `+,- or =`. so the result ia `a b c 4x` and the length of this array is `4`